# How to Install a ODBC driver on the Azure Integration Runtime machine?

Tags: azure, installation, odbc, azure-data-factory

The following link states that a prerequisite for copying data sources using Azure Data Factory is to install an ODBC driver in the Azure Runtime Environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odbc

However, I can't find anything that documents how to do this. I would expect that many, many people have either done this or need this information. It's a simple exercise on a Windows Server. I have the installer file which I ran on my Windows server and now the driver is present there.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi@Frank If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Prerequisites**
To use this ODBC connector, we need to:

- Set up a Self-hosted Integration Runtime(not Azure Integration Runtime).See [Self-hosted Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime) article for details.
- Install the 64-bit ODBC driver for the data store on the Integration Runtime machine.

At Intergration runtime setup,we can see Azure Integration Runtime is not supproted.
[image]

1. After we installed Self-hosted Integration Runtime on the machine and registered with the Authentication key. Then we can new a linked service (ODBC).
   [image]
2. Enter the Linked service properties:
   [image]

After that we can connect to the DB Server via ODBC connector.

Comment: I need a specific driver. I have the driver install package. Can I run that package on the self-hosted integration runtime? If so, a starting point would be great. Thanks for the clarification on using the self-hosted runtime. There was no mention of that in the article that I was referencing.

Comment: Yes, we should  install driver package on the self-hosted integration runtime.

Comment: So, what would be the point of having a self-hosted integration runtime if I have an on-premises server? Why not just do all the work on my on-prem server?

Comment: 1: After we installed a self-hosted integration runtime, it is equivalent to creating a VPN. Then ADF can access your server like locally. 2: Install the ODBC Driver at your on-prem server. 3: Using ODBC connector, which can connect to your  on-prem server ODBC data source.

Comment: Hi guys! I'm trying to create this ODBC data source to keep my PowerBI data on cloud. But it doesn't make sense when we have to have a on premises server. Sounds like we are running in circles and spending money, don't you agree?

Answer (score 2):

Yea I had the same problem. So you can't install anything on the default Azure IR. If you want to install something custom on your IR, you can do that on the other two types of IR, self hosted and SSIS.

For self hosted you need to have a VM somewhere, ours are on-prem but if you just need it to use some custom drivers you can just make a VM in azure. There is a self hosted exe app you download and install on that VM. Than you use a token generated via self hosted IR, paste it into self hosted agent app installed on VM, and they are connected. Install whatever driver you want on that VM and should work as far as I know, I haven't had any issues.

For SSIS-IR you need to that driver inside of a SSIS package. To install the driver you connect the SSIS-IR to a container via a token or whatever, and inside that container there is a main.cmd file where you can script to install whatever you want. This can be a pain to get working, here is some code I used to install some drivers.

```
echo Installing ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server...
msiexec /i msodbcsql.msi /quiet /passive /qn /lv %CUSTOM_SETUP_SCRIPT_LOG_DIR%\msodbcsql.log IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES ADDLOCAL=ALL
echo Installation completed

echo Installing OLE DB Driver for SQL Server...
msiexec /i msoledbsql.msi /quiet /passive /qn /lv %CUSTOM_SETUP_SCRIPT_LOG_DIR%\msoledbsql.log IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES
echo Installation completed

%~dp0\ServiceNowODBC64\setup.exe /s
```