# ODBC DataSource - How to keep data on Azure cloud to source PowerBI?

Tags: azure, powerbi, odbc

I have a ODBC datasource and I'd need to use it with PowerBI. It works fine locally.
In order to refresh data and keep user up to date, I need to send this data do cloud (Azure/BlobStorage) then PowerBI can connect directly into Blob Storage and consume the data.

As discussed here [stackoverflow-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65081902/how-to-install-a-odbc-driver-on-the-azure-integration-runtime-machine) , we need an on-premises server to have this ODBC running.

It sounds a quite confusing to me as we need the data on cloud, using ODBC as datasource and "publishing" the data with Blob Storage, and for that, we do need a local server.

I'm very begginer with Azure Cloud but... don't we have any other way to have this process configured without local server or a expensive Virtual Machine on Azure? Looks like we are running in circles here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your options:

1. Install [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) (standard mode) on a server to host the ODBC driver
2. Install [Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/) (personal mode) on your PC to host the ODBC driver
3. Copy the data to Azure (Blob Storage or Azure SQL Database, etc), and configure the Power BI Model to load the data from there instead of ODBC
4. Manually refresh your data in Power BI Desktop and re-publish it to Power BI whenever the data needs to be updated.

For Option 3 you can use any tool you want to copy the data to Azure.  Azure Data Factory is one option, and for that you would need to install the [Self-Hosted Integration Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory) to host the ODBC driver.  But you can also extract the data to files and copy them to Auzre Storage with [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy).

Comment: David, the option 3 sounds best. But how can I copy the data to Azure as the only option is via ODBC? To copy the data it must be generated via ODBC+Query and save the results in a file that will be copied, right? 
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Yes.  You would use some tool or program to connect to the data source, run a query, and write the results as a file.

Comment: David, do you mean tool or program outside Azure, right?

Comment: Yes.  Azure can't load your ODBC driver and connect to your data source.  So you need _something_ that can to access the data.  That _could_ be a VM in Azure if you have a S2S VPN configured, or something running on your PC or a server in your data center.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But this is the exactly my issue. I'm trying to avoid any manual process or virtual machine or local server. That's why i mentioned that looks like we're running in circles. To keep a data in the cloud, we need a local server or VM. :-)

Thanks for your help!